# Coinbase API, some currencies are missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptocurrency, coinbase-api

I tried this in python:

```
from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
from coinbase.wallet.error import AuthenticationError

import config

class API:
    def auth():
        try:
            client = Client(config.API_KEY, config.API_SECRET)

            accounts = client.get_accounts()
            for wallet in accounts.data:
                print(str(wallet['balance']['currency']) )
        except AuthenticationError:
            print("Login failed!")
```

and got a lot of currency names, but none of the ones I own.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Got it. For some reason, not all currencies are listed here.

```py
ethAccount = client.get_account('ETH')
print(str(ethAccount['name']) + ' ' + str(ethAccount['balance']['amount']))
```